# Why is TextWatcher event being triggered even after it's removed?

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to keep a class variable updated any time the EditText's text changes.  But for some reason, after setting the EditText's text, `afterTextChanged` gets fired with the old value that was in the EditText.  This happens even though I'm removing the TextWatcher before setting the text.  Any idea what's going on?

```
private EditText mEditCost;
private String mCost;

private TextWatcher myWatcher = new MyTextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
    {
        mCost = mEditCost.getText().toString();
    }
};

@Override
protected View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_costs, container, false);
    mEditCost = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_cost);
    setCost();
    return rootView;
}

private void setCost()
{
    mEditCost.removeTextChangedListener(myWatcher);
    mEditCost.setText(mCost);
    mEditCost.addTextChangedListener(myWatcher);
}
```

Comment: have you tried creating a new instance of `myWatcher` before you create a new listener?

Comment: You might try `onTextChanged()` instead of `afterTextChanged()`

Comment: I've tried both those things but the listener still triggers with the old value after I re-add it

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the watcher gets notified after the text is changed in the UI, which happens when the UI thread returns after your call to `addTextChangedListener`.


Try adding the watcher on the next UI thread loop:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable(){

   @Override
   public void run(){
       mEditCost.addTextChangedListener(myWatcher);
   }
});
```

Comment: When I try this, the watcher does not get called again like it was before, but the EditText still is set to its old value.